# TEIID Springboot integration

Tags: teiid

i read about Teiid and i liked it, but because it has a lot of changes, i got some problems first to deal with it, but what i understand now is the following:

1- teiid wildfly and thorntail are going to be obsolete, so, i will not use them.
2- teiid spring boot and openshift are the most active projects now, so, i chose one of them which is sprintboot.

my thoughts for using teiid in springboot is for the following:

1- integrate my different schemas in a micro-service architecture pattern to solve the problem of data integrity for all services.
2- create a standalone data virtualization (data warehouse) for my internal database systems to be used in reporting.

for the reporting system, i created a ddl vdb file, and i was able to deploy springboot application with jdbc enabled, and used the existing Simple-java-client to connect to it, but i tried to use apache superset to get my reports in a BI application, and i enabled the ODBC with the postgres, but i always have the below error

Connection failed (psycopg2.OperationalError) TEIID30528 javax.transaction.SystemException: The system is only setup for spring managed transactions.  If you need Teiid to manage transactions, then a third-party transaction manager like narayana-spring-boot-starter needs to be configured.
DETAIL:  org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID30528 javax.transaction.SystemException: The system is only setup for spring managed transactions.  If you need Teiid to manage transactions, then a third-party transaction manager like narayana-spring-boot-starter needs to be configured.

although i tried to integrate with narayana, but i couldn't configure it,
sorry for this long discussion, but i need to know:

1- is the above approach is good, or should i try other things.

2- is the above error has any fix or there is any other suggested BI tool i can use with Teiid?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot for your help, and by adding the below dependency to the POM file

```
 <dependency> 
 <groupid>me.snowdrop</groupid>
 <artifactid>narayana-spring-boot-starter</artifactid>
 <version>2.1.0</version>
```

and adding narayana.dbcp.enabled=true, spring.jta.enabled=true to the application.properties, i could do some graphs using the apache superset.

also, as long as wildly is still supported, i will go on for the wildfly solution, as it is more suitable to have more VDBs in a single container.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What I can say (https://teiid.io/blog/post-2020-3) Teiid won't be obsolete for WildFly. The Teiid supports currently the [WildFly](http://teiid.io/teiid_wildfly/) and Spring Boot as could be found on their pages. If you are looking for the Java EE components and the best integration amongst other JBoss projects (e.g. Narayana) then you could try to check the WildFly version of Teiid. It's right that Thorntail develoment efforts are decreases for the sake of [Quarkus](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus). But it seems (as the post above mentions) the Teiid considers the support of Quarkus. But WildFly is(!) still supported.

On your question about the setup of the third party transaction manager for Spring Boot and with Narayana in particular you should check information from Snowdrop project and the README of the [Narayana Spring Boot integration](https://github.com/snowdrop/narayana-spring-boot).

The thing which should be enough to configure the Narayana starter is to add the starter to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-narayana</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If there is a need for configuring Narayana in particular the configuration properties start with [`spring.jta.narayana`](http://jbossts.blogspot.com/2016/06/narayana-in-spring-boot.html)

Comment: Yes, WildFly version is not going away. Thorntail version certainly is. yes, Spring Boot version is more in microservices or smaller footprint where single VDB is a deployment per VM model needed or optionally to work with JPA like development model. For Superset you can add `<dependency>
  <groupid>me.snowdrop</groupid>
  <artifactid>narayana-spring-boot-starter</artifactid>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>` to your pom.xml file as dependency